# How can I build a specific ROS2 package only?

Tags: ros, ros2, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have pulled all ROS2 repos into my overlay workspace using

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/release-latest/ros2.repos
vcs import src < ros2.repos
```

How can I build one specific package and its dependencies only? Let's say I want to build `rcl` with `ament build --only-packages rcl` this will not work because of the directory structure in `src` where `rcl` resides in `src/ros2/rcl`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284846/how-can-i-build-a-specific-ros2-package-only?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-03-08**:
The location of `rcl` in the `src` folder doesn't matter when using `--only`, because it matches package names, not folder locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd also add to @tfoote's answer:

> How can I build one specific package and its dependencies only?

You cannot currently do that, `--end-with rcl` will build all packages that would have been built before `rcl` whether or not `rcl` depends on them.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-03-08**:
Means its not possible to combine `--start-with` with `--end-with` then?